# Trigger null point exception error

Tags: before-trigger

I am writing a trigger for Before Insert and hitting null point exception error when trying to add ids to a list.

```
if(trigger.Isbefore){
   if(trigger.Isinsert){
     List<Id> acid;
     List<id> conid;
     for(Contact a: trigger.new){
     system.debug('a.id'+a.id); // get the a.id= null in debug
     system.debug('a.Account'+a.Account); // get the id value in debug but getting null exception error when adding to list
       conid.add(a.id);
       acid.add(a.Account);
     }
   }     
}
```

Comment: Is this trigger on contact ? and which line is giving null pointer

Comment: no actually on one of my custom object, I replicated the issue I was facing

Comment: While it isn't pertinent to why you're getting the Null Pointer Exception, it's good to keep in mind that records in `Trigger.new` in a `before insert` context have not yet been assigned an Id. If you need access to the Id in a trigger context variable in an `insert` context, your code must be run `after insert`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your lists before using them:

```
List<Id> acid = new Id[0];
List<id> conid = new Id[0];
```

You must always have a non-null value in a variable before you can use any of its methods.